# Mute/Unmute with mouse click on YouTube video

Tags: javascript, iframe, video, youtube

I am trying to create an interactive page with YouTube videos. I want to display multiple videos on a page, and the user can only mute or unmute the videos. So there are no controls, just click on a video to either turn the audio on or off. They all autoplay at the same time. Can anyone please help me?

thank you

P.S. Here is what I have so far, not sure if iframe is the right code:

```css
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PN-gI9nTIyE?&autoplay=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Hi William, welcome to Stack ! You can use the `<code></code>` function (button available on the text editor) to share with us what you have done so far. It will help localize your issue.

Comment: Hi Zeratops,

Thanks, I updated the post!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("video").prop('muted', true); //mute
```

AND

```
$("video").prop('muted', false); //unmute
```

See all events [here](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)

(side note: use `attr` if in jQuery < 1.6)

Comment: Hi JJJ,

Thanks for the help. How do I add that to an iframe code? Or do I need to use a different type?
This is what I have so far:

<code>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/PN-gI9nTIyE?&autoplay=1&fs=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</code>